# Prove that a unique solution to $y'=1+\sqrt[5]{y-x}$ passes through each point of the region $(x-2)^2+(y-4)^2=1$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Prove that a unique solution to $y'=1+\sqrt[5]{y-x}$ passes through each point of the region $(x-2)^2+(y-4)^2=1$.

At first, I tried to solve the given diff. eq., but my attempt was unsuccessful. The power of $5$ seems to overcomplicate the matters.

Then I thought of the region itself. It's obvious that it is circle with the center in $(2;4)$ and radius $r=1$. But how can I apply this to the initial diff. eq.? I would be glad if someone could give me a hint.

Comment: For solving the diff. eq. put $u^5+x=y$, then $y'=1+5u^4u'$ and therefore the equation becomes $5u^4u'=u$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

$$
((y-x)')^5=y-x
$$

so making $z = y-x$ we have

$$
(z')^5=z
$$

which is separable.

Comment: Okay, $y=\pm \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^\frac{5}{4}x^\frac{5}{4}+x$. But how is this solution connected to the region?

Comment: The solution $$y = \frac{4\sqrt{2}}{5^{\frac 54}}(C_0+x)^{\frac 54}+x$$ for $-2\le C_0\le 3$ covers all the set of points $(x-2)^2+(y-4)^2=1$